# z-index issue in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

We have a `z-index` problem with a `div` that's supposed to be over a particular `div`. The `div` named (house-over-banner) is absolute, whilst the one below it is relative.

In Firefox, IE6, 8 - it shows all good!
Just in IE7, it doesn't!

The link is http://www.showhome3d.com.au. - it's the house over the banner on the right hand side of the page.

Comment: It looks fine to me in IEs 6 , 7, and 8 in IETester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dirty css trick is to make parent div relative while the child div absolute. This way child div won't escape out of the parent div but you have not done something like that, you might do it that way to see if this works for you. Also z-index only works with elements which are set to absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt work out how to reply to Calebs Post so ill just post here,

im one of the team working with caleb on this (we are all combining forces to slay this beast of an issue :P ) but what appears to be happening now is that sometimes it will work in IE 7 and then other times it wont..its just chance when the page loads as to if it will be on top of below.

We applied a jquery z-index fix (http://www.vancelucas.com/blog/fixing-ie7-z-index-issues-with-jquery/comment-page-1/) which has seemed to cause this behaviour but its weird that it is not consistent

Answer (score 0):

positioned elements in IE 6 and 7 form their own z-index stacking context, which is unescapable.